# PHP str_getcsv to JSON

Tags: php, json, csv

I am trying to use str_getcsv to convert from CSV to JSON.

I'm nearly there the problem I am having is with formatting the JSON,
I need the format to be like this to use in DataTables -

```
{"data":[["Debra Brown"]
```

But it is

```
{"data":["[[\"Debra Brown\"]
```

My code

```
$csv = file_get_contents($targetPath);
$csvArray = array_map("str_getcsv", file($targetPath));
$csvToJson = json_encode($csvArray);

print_r($csv);

$csvJsonArray = array();

$csvJsonArray['data'][] = $csvToJson;
echo json_encode($csvJsonArray);
```

My CSV - [CSV](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ny9hyPtGrifh5OFWFbiQD-yFpkG3RbnFvoG_YQwwVPA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You re-encode already encoded string.

Add `data` key before encoding data:

```
$csvArray = array_map( 'str_getcsv', file( $targetPath ) );
$csvArray = array( 'data' => $csvArray );
$csvToJson = json_encode( $csvArray );
```

Result:

```
{"data":[["Debra Brown"],["Jacqueline Garza"], (...) ]}
```